# AngularJS date validation

Tags: angularjs, validation, angular-ui-datepicker

How can I do date control validation in an AngularJS form for the following code ?

```
<label for="startDate" class="control-label">Start Date:</label>
<div class="">
    <input type="date" class="form-control" 
           id="startDate" ng-model="startDate" />
</div>

<label for="endDate" class="control-label">End Date:</label>
<div class="">
    <input type="date" class="form-control" 
           id="endDate" ng-model="endDate" />
</div>

<div class="alert alert-warning" ng-show="">
    // ??
</div>
```

If only one of the dates are entered, then the form should prompt to enter the other date. If both dates are empty, or both are entered, then it should successfully submit the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you dont want to use any controller or js and want to do it with pure HTML. Try this Method

Edit your HTML to :

```
<label for="startDate" class="control-label">Start Date:</label>
<div class="">
    <input type="date" class="form-control" 
           id="startDate" ng-model="startDate" />
</div>

<label for="endDate" class="control-label">End Date:</label>
<div class="">
    <input type="date" class="form-control" 
           id="endDate" ng-model="endDate" />
</div>

<div class="alert alert-warning" ng-show="!startDate && endDate ||startDate && !endDate ">
    // Do what ever you want to do here 
</div>
```

Added this answer too so that you can choose which ever best suits you. If you want to do more functionality on the submit I highly suggest you using the Controller. If you are just interested in the UI go ahead with the simple HTML solution

Comment: Pure and simple client-side validation, this solution works perfectly for me. Thanks!

Comment: Glad that I could help you out :)

Comment: Making use of ngRequired might be better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pull this off by attaching  controller. There check if $scope.startDate is empty or not. If !empty, then $scope.endDate has to be !empty, else no error.

` $scope.startDate = null;
  $scope.endDate = null;
if( !$scope.startDate ) {

if(!$scope.endDate) { $scope.error = false }

} else { if( !$scope.endDate ) { $scope.error = true; $scope.reason = "Enter valid end date." } }`

Comment: The problem with this is that $scope.startDate (or $scope.endDate) do not equal null if you pick a date and then clear it . What is the value after clearing if it is not null ?

Comment: Null is just for the example..Usually it's an empty string. Do a check for that.

Answer (score 0):

This is my approach to solve your question

The HTML

```
<label for="startDate" class="control-label">Start Date:</label>
<div class="" >
    <input type="date" class="form-control" 
           id="startDate" ng-model="startDate" />
</div>

<label for="endDate" class="control-label">End Date:</label>
<div class="">
    <input type="date" class="form-control" 
           id="endDate" ng-model="endDate" />

</div>
<span>{{errMessage}}</span>
    <button ng-click='checkErr(startDate,endDate)'>Submit</button>
```

Add this Code into your Controller for the HTML

```
$scope.checkErr = function(startDate,endDate){
    $scope.errMessage = '';

    if(!startDate && endDate){
      $scope.errMessage = 'please Enter Start Date';
      return false;
    }
    if(!endDate && startDate){
       $scope.errMessage = 'please Enter End Date';
       return false;
    }
    if(endDate && startDate || !endDate && !startDate ){
       $scope.errMessage ='Successfully Submitted';
       // you can add you submit function here  
    }
  };
```

This will throw the error message above the submit button if either of the dates are entered and one is left. It will show which of the dates the user should enter and if both the dates are entered or both of the dates are not entered it will show successfully submitted . you can add your submit function in the if case.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can call this scope function for any sort of date validations make sure on ng-submit you trigger dateValidator(year,month,date)

```
$scope.dateValidator = function(year, month, date) {

  var dates = new Date(year, month - 1, date);
  if (dates.getFullYear() == year && dates.getMonth() + 1 == month && dates.getDate() == date) {
    alertify.success('Valid Date');

  } else {
    alertify.error('Invalid date');
    return false;
  }
};
```